# What does gamma refer to?

Tags: image

trying to undertand imadjust and i referred to its docs here https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imadjust.html#bujj02g-1

but i can't understand what the values between 0 and 1 are like for a grayscale image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RGB scale

rgb ranged from `0 to 255` is transformed to the scale `0~1` as follow

```
x in range [0 255] --> y = x/255 --> y corresponding of x in scale [0 1]
```

For example

```
y = 0.6 (scale [0 1]) --> x = 255*y = 255*0.6 = 153 (scale  [0 255] )
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your answer. You currently have everything in a code block.

Answer (score 1):

All input values are raised to the power of gamma before multiplication (mapping input range to output range):

```
out_value = alpha + beta * in_value ^ gamma
```

This enables non-linear mapping, for example, gamma < 1 will give more detail to dark areas.
See "Gamma Correction" in wiki for more details:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction

Comment: too complicated

Comment: You should get familiar with power operator, or exponent. The input value is the base and the exponent is gamma. exponentiation corresponds to repeated multiplication. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation